# How to access video element inside div

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and i was wondering can I access the video element thats inside the div element?

```
<div id="player" class="player">

        <video id="element"></video>

</div>
```

Comment: How do you access the div element? Can't you access the video element [by id](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) ?

Answer (score 1):

In pure javascript?

for that you'd use something like `var video = document.getElementById('element');`

[here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Morklympious/yt704285/)

I added a console.log statement so you can see the element showing up in the developer console.

Answer (score 1):

Since the element has an `id`, you can simply get it directly :

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById("element");
```

If it didn't have an id for some reasons, you could do that :

```
var myVideo = document.querySelector("#player video");
```

That's very basic JS so you can find help on that anywhere. And specifically on querySelector [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector), for example.

Answer (score 0):

`var el = document.getElementById("element");`

If you were using jQuery you could target it like this:

`var el = $('video#element');`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use regular javaScript to access the video element, but using it's `id` and the `getElementById` function.

```
var video = document.getElementById('element');
// Play Video
video.play();
```

If you're using jQuery, you can also do this:

```
var $video = $("#element");
$video.get(0).play();
```

Comment: `document.getElementById()` doesn't take a hash (#) when specifying it's parameters, I don't think. Closest you get to jQuery is probably `document.querySelector('#element')`

Comment: Indeed, no hash, or it would match an element with id="#element"